# Notation $\Delta= \partial^{j}\partial_{j}$ for Laplace operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

In a PDE script I read the following definition of the Laplace operator. But I really don't see how that could be.

$\Delta= \partial^{j}\partial_{j}$

The Laplace operator gives me the sum of the second derivatives over all dimensions. This seems to be a mix of Einstein summation and multiindex notation.

For me this reads for $d=3$:

$\sum_{j=1}^{d} \partial^{j}\partial_{j} = \partial^{1}\partial_{1} + \partial^{2}\partial_{2} + \partial^{3}\partial_{3}$

Where does the second derivative come into play?

Comment: As long as you stick to flat spaces, $\partial^1\partial_1=\partial_{xx}$

Comment: Do you know what is $\partial^i$?

Comment: Really it should read $\nabla^i\nabla_i$.